# How to encode into\decode from UTF-8 string in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, utf-8

So I have a string like `&#1056;&#1091;&#1089;&#1089;&#1082;&#1086;&#1077; &#1048;&#1084;&#1103;` how to represent it as real string with wcf textBox? And How to encode for example russian string inputed into textInput into UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decode this and other HTML encoded strings, use `HtmlDecode()` like below:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#1056;&#1091;&#1089;&#1089;&#1082;&#1086;&#1077; &#1048;&#1084;&#1103;")
```

This decodes to `Русское Имя`. As for UTF-8, just like bwreichle said, you can use:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"Русское Имя")
```